# Highly Customizable App in C# (Like Apache Ofbiz)

Tags: c#, architecture

I have recently been exploring Apache Ofbiz and was impressed by its ability to customize most areas of the application: UI, workflow, entities.

Is there any similar (not necessarily an ERP system)  application developed in C#/.Net which offers a similar level of customization?

I am looking for examples of applications developed in C# that are highly customizable in terms of UI, Workflow and Entity Model

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite what you are asking for, but have a look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF), a good toolkit for customisable applications in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I actually worked on such an application, it's called Synergi (www.synergi.com). The workflow and UI is basically described in a database and rendered (ASP.net) on the client. Contact me or the company if you want more information. :)